# Having issue in calling Tophatter product upload API

Tags: php, api

I'm using tophatter php library and found error Class 'ProductApi'  not found ? Any one have any idea about it?
 I am trying many times the same thing but unfortunately, the issue is occurring again and again and I failed to upload product on tophatter please help.

following is the code:

```
<?php
require('TophatterMerchant/TophatterMerchantApi.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/ProductApi.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/VariationApi.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/OrderApi.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/MetadataApi.php');

require('TophatterMerchant/Model/Schema.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Exception/BadRequestException.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Model/Product.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Model/Variation.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Model/Order.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Model/Metadata.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Exception/UnauthorizedException.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Exception/BadContentTypeException.php');
require('TophatterMerchant/Exception/NotFoundException.php');

use TophatterMerchant\TophatterMerchantApi;
use TophatterMerchant\VariationApi;
use TophatterMerchant\OrderApi;
use TophatterMerchant\MetadataApi;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\BadContentTypeException;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\BadRequestException;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\NotFoundException;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\ServerErrorException;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use TophatterMerchant\Exception\ConnectionException;

TophatterMerchantApi::setAccessToken('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 $product = array(
                //product details
           );


        $json_response =ProductApi::create($args);
```

Comment: Whenever I update an existing product that is live, it does not seem to update.  If I disable, then update, then it updates right away via the API.  Any additional insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to just add a line

```
use TophatterMerchant\ProductApi;
```

Through this line, you can easily upload the products